# Kinect v2 "No devices connected..." I've tried everything

Tags: ros, usb, freenect, libfreenect, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm at the point, I've tried literally everything for weeks now to get any kind of visualization and no dice because of No devices connected error.

I'm on an intel i7 w/ hd graphics 4k
running ubuntu trusty 14.04lts
trying to get visualization on ros indigo

First I tried getting it all to run in a virtual machine, I thought that was my big problem that Virtualbox would not recognize USB 3.0 devices. So I abandoned that and partitioned my drive & installed ubuntu. Went through a bunch of stuff trying to get openni and openni2 to work, eventually finding out that that is for the 360 device. So now I tried libfreenect2 & freenect but still can not get passed the no devices connected error.

My lsusb lists the kinect in 3 places as it should. I don't know where to go from here.
I tried 'protonect' from libfreenect2 but I get an error about openCL on there.

Can someone walk me through it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207047/kinect-v2-%22no-devices-connected...%22-i%27ve-tried-everything./) by [divorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/22138/divorce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2015-05-28**:
When you download libfreenect2 there's a rules folder.
Did you copy the file 90-kinect2.rules in your /etc/udev/rules.d/ folder ?
You can run Protonect with cpu from the bin folder, to test if you can visualize the data :

```
./Protonect cpu
```

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-12-19**:
I your Kinect a model 1473? If so this question may help you: http://answers.ros.org/question/196455/kinect-installation-and-setup-on-ros-updated/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

It seems that usb 3 is not well recognized on linux kernel < 3.13 so it doesn't work on every machine.

EDIT: try georg l answer before, this will tell you directly if you have a permission issue or if the problem is elsewhere. Otherwise here is how I sovled it on my laptop.

I've installed ubuntu14.04.2 which uses the newer kernel versions and kinect2 is working fine on it.
I followed the steps  listed [here](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2).

note: if you use 14.04.2, you'll need to install a bunch of X libraries, most of them are listed on the [ROS installation page](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation-1).
note2: the registration of the kinect2 point clouds is done on the computer, which take a huge amount of computing power, I'm trying to figure out how to make the GPU perform the registration. On an i7 laptop the framerate drops to 5~6 fps when you perform the registration.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same  issue with a kinect v1 and the freenect stack. Try to change the permissions of the usb bus

```
 sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/bus/usb
```

---

Originally posted by [georg l](https://answers.ros.org/users/22092/georg-l/) with karma: 186 on 2015-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Imesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31664/imesh/) on 2018-01-22**:
This helped me with ubuntu mate 16.04.2 with ROS Kinetic on Raspbery pi 3. Thanks..